# When I run my daemon the service is a http proxy instead off http

Tags: http, google-cloud-platform, daemon, http-proxy

I am currently running a service with systemctl, and it is running as an http proxy, not normal http. Is this something that Google does? I am using port 8080 and I can't connect to it via http. My daemon is using port 8080, while using the type http-proxy (I am seeing this with the command `nmap -sV -sC -p 8080 35.208.25.61 -vvvv -Pn`). Instead, I want the daemon I'm running (wings.service) to use http, so it can use that type of connection to connect to my panel.

The panel is part of a piece of software along with the daemon, it's called [pterodactyl](https://pterodactyl.io). Anyways, I have tried everything on what to do, and I think this problem that I am addressing is the problem that causes dysfunction on my panel. I might just have to move to a different service to host my bots for discord.

Let me know if there's anything I can do to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

As per I can understand you are unable to access the panel via web URL.

Pterodactyl web server can be installed using NGINX or Apache [web servers](https://pterodactyl.io/panel/0.7/webserver_configuration.html), and both web servers by default listed on port 80 based on Pterodactyl web server installation guide, so you must enable HTTP port 80 traffic on your Compute Engine VM instance

The default firewall rules on GCP do not allow HTTP or HTTPS connections to your instances. However, it is fairly simple to add a rule that does allow them [following this steps](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/special-configurations#externalhttpconnection):

1.-Go to the VM instances page.
2.- Click the name of the desired instance.
3.- Click Edit button at the top of the page.
4.- Scroll down to the Firewalls section.
5.- Check the Allow HTTP or Allow HTTPS options under your desired VPC network.
6.- Click Save.

Note: The Pterodactyl panel and Daemon installation are not the same for each operating system, if after checking the VPC firewall rules on the VM settings and also the status of the web server in the instance (NGINX or Apache) you still cannot access your panel, please provide a step by step list with all commands you followed to complete the installation, including the OS version you used.